# Ember initializing route model with query

Tags: ember.js

I am trying to initialize a Route's model with a DS query, as follows

```
App.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('post', { path: '/posts/:post_slug' });
});

App.PostsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params) {
        var records = App.Post.find({ slug: params.post_slug });
        return records.get('firstObject');
    }
});
```

Here, i find a Post by its slug and set the first result as the route model. but since `records` is populated asynchronously, the model data is not set properly. What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solved this with Deferred pattern.

```
App.PostsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params) {
        var records = App.Post.find({ slug: params.post_slug });
        var promise = Ember.Deferred.create();
        records.addObserver('isLoaded', function() {
            promise.resolve(records.get('firstObject'));
        });
        return promise;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the question and big thanks for your answer !! A comment though, the route name should be PostRoute (singular form), c/d ?

Comment: shouldn't you call removeObserver for best practice when you resolve the promise.

Answer (score 0):

That should do that trick:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('posts');
  this.resource('post', { path: '/posts/:post_id' });
});

App.PostsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return App.Post.find();
  }
});

App.PostRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    return App.Post.find(params.post_id);
  }
});
```

Comment: I have corrected a typo. I am trying to find the post by its slug, by running a query. i do not want use the post_id in the route path.

Comment: @z33m you would still have to use `App.Post.find(post_id)` but there's has to be a method defined in your controller. could you clarify what you're trying to do through an example? maybe jsfiddle?